# Charting cumulative returns of a non time-based object

Tags: r, charts

I have a vector of asset returns without dates in each row.

Is there a similar method as `chart.CumReturns` from package `PerformanceAnalytics` that does not require having to have a vector, dataframe etc. which is a time-based object (I do not have dates in rows).

Comment: Why not compute the cumulated returns yourself 
(`cumsum(x)` if you have log-returns and want log-returns,
`exp1m(cumsum(log1p(x)))` if you have ratio-returns and want ratio-returns)
and plot them with `plot`?

Comment: Good Idea, however would not be the chart different than the ((1+return)at time 1*(1+return)at time 2)-1 calculation

Comment: That is equivalent, but the taking the sum of the log-returns is more numerically stable 
than `cumprod(1+x)` (on a plot, you are unlikely to see any difference, unless the series are very long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep all the functionality of `chart.CumReturns` and appearance of plots generated by the function, you may create fake dates, convert the vector to a format that `chart.CumReturns` accepts (e.g. `xts` or `zoo`), and then plot using `chart.CumReturns` with the fake x axis removed. It seems that `chart.CumReturns` does not handle `order.by = index(x)`, thus you need a 'real' date.

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(xts)

# an example vector
vec <- coredata(edhec)[ , "Funds of Funds"]

# create fake dates, e.g.: 
date <- seq(Sys.Date(), by = "1 month", length.out = length(vec))

# convert to xts (or zoo) object 
xt <- xts(x = vec, order.by = date)

# plot without fake x axis
chart.CumReturns(xt, main = "Cumulative Returns", xaxis = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, one last question,how would you add the dates to a data frame so I can chart several columns in one sole chart

Comment: SOLVED x<-data.frame(xt1,xt2,xt3)
chart.CumReturns(x, main = "Cumulative Returns", xaxis = FALSE,col="red")